# https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination class="pagination pagination-lg" not working in bootstrap 4

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am new in angularjs. I am using https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/pagination. I have some problem : style class="pagination pagination-lg" not working, I am using bootstrap version 4. Help me.Thanks

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bCEX3.png)

**index.html**

```
<div>
        <pre>You are currently on page {{userCtrl.page}}</pre>
        <ul uib-pagination total-items="userCtrl.totalElements" ng-model="userCtrl.page" max-size="10000" class="pagination pagination-lg"
            boundary-links="true" num-pages="userCtrl.totalPages">
        </ul>
    </div>
```

**userController.js**

```
module.exports = function (UserService) {
    var _this = this;
    _this.users = [];
    _this.page = [];
    _this.size = [];
    _this.totalElements = [];
    _this.totalPages = [];

    _this.list = function () {
        UserService.getUsersPage().then(function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            _this.users = response.content;
            _this.page = response.number;
            _this.size = response.numberOfElements;
            _this.totalElements = response.totalElements;
            _this.totalPages = response.totalPages;
        })
    };
    _this.list();
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check pagination component DOM structure? uiBootstrap is tested with version 3.3.6, so comparing both versions:

**v3:**

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li>
      <a href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**v4:**

```
<nav aria-label="Page navigation">
  <ul class="pagination">
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Previous">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">1</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">2</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">3</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">4</a></li>
    <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">5</a></li>
    <li class="page-item">
      <a class="page-link" href="#" aria-label="Next">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

I'm sure you see missing css classes on elements in v3 ;)